# Put JSON data into grid via JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

Hoping there was an easy json grid plugin somewhere.  I have a need to fill a grid via JSON/Ajax, the issue is the amount of data or columns will nearly always be different so it needs to adapt accordingly.

i.e. Parameter is passed via jQuery ajax call, sql is configured and run against database this could be any fields/tables, needs to then somehow return rows and populate a grid/div

I am using ASP .Net c#, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery UI team are building one ...

http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/02/unleash-the-grid/

and reference existing possibilities:

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki

http://www.trirand.com/blog/

http://www.datatables.net/

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

http://flexigrid.info/

http://reconstrukt.com/ingrid/

Comment: I have looked at http://www.datatables.net/ and it seemed to off most of what I needed

Comment: +1 for datatables - it's the easiest to setup and use, and gives lots of flexibility.